# why "multi foo" parsed value is "(multi multi2) foo"

Tags: java, lucene

so sorry my poor English, hope you can see what I say.

In Lucene3 Junit test code : org.apache.lucene.queryParser.TestMultiAnalyzer.testMultiAnalyzer()

```
QueryParser qp = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "", new MultiAnalyzer());

 // two tokens at the same position:
assertEquals("(multi multi2) foo", qp.parse("multi foo").toString());
assertEquals("foo (multi multi2)", qp.parse("foo multi").toString());
```

I don't understand why "multi foo" parsed value is "(multi multi2) foo".

I'm searched in google.com and baidu.com, no result.

Comment: We'll need to know what the method `qp.parse` does. Which class does that belong to? Do you have the Javadoc for it?

Comment: You are writing the test case for that and you don't know why it parses like that then how can we know without looking at the code.

Comment: It's not my test code, it's luence's test code.HOHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've taken the test code from [TestMultiAnalyzer.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/src/test/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/TestMultiAnalyzer.java). If you look at the code, you can see the Javadoc and definition of the class `MultiAnalyzer`:

```
/**
 * Expands "multi" to "multi" and "multi2", both at the same position,
 * and expands "triplemulti" to "triplemulti", "multi3", and "multi2".  
 */
private class MultiAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
    // <snipped>
}
```

So, the Javadoc explains what's going on: "multi" will become "multi multi2". If you want to know exactly why this happens, debug through the code and read all relevant Javadoc. Ask questions here if you get stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

The `MultiAnalyzer` class (defined [in the same Java file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/src/test/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/TestMultiAnalyzer.java)) has the comment:

```
/**
 * Expands "multi" to "multi" and "multi2", both at the same position,
 * and expands "triplemulti" to "triplemulti", "multi3", and "multi2".  
 */
```

Which probably explains it...